# Lowest permission level to see the content of a file?

Tags: security, permissions

How can I see the contents of a file with 111 permissions? A thing called [Y-combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_combinator), as an input, prints the content of a file. My instinct says that you can run it with 100 permissions. However, I know only the theory, not the practise.

> Which is the lowest permission level to see a file with Y-combinator in Bash?

The user nobody_ comments:

> You don't make any sense. The Y combinator is used to create recursive functions and has nothing to do with permissions.

A question arises:

> Which is the lowest permission level to see a file in Bash?

Comment: You don't make any sense. The Y combinator is used to create recursive functions and has nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: I don't get the "Y Combinator" reference either, can it be some kind of search/replace mishap? That doesn't explain how it got into the title, though. Strange.

Comment: @nobody_ I added your response to the question. Perhaps, I just mixed up things. The goal is still the same. I am looking for the lowest permission level to see the content of a file. It may be executable, or not.

Comment: Found this question by "Y combinator in Bash" search query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a file (script or otherwise), you need to be able to load its content into memory, hence to have read access.

So only leaving execution rights on your files is not going to allow anybody to read it. However, this is still a *bad* idea. Nothing that *should not* be executed should receive execution rights. In your position, I would be much more worried in accidentally executing a text file that begins with rm * than somebody using tricks to peek at my files.

Comment: My file only has a line "rm *" with 700 permissions. I try to remove the content of the fonder, where the file is lacated. Do I do it like      "./file"? It asks me a weird question: "override --------x  user/staff for some_file?" What should I do to remove the content?

Comment: This is something you probably should have asked as a separate question. However, the reason is simple: rm sees you don't have write rights on the file some_file, and asks you if you want to bypass that protection. Honestly, I think your whole file permission scheme is very weird...

Answer (score 1):

You can't read the contents of a file with those permissions.

Permissions of '111' are 'execute only' and are almost useless on a regular file.  In order for a file to be executed it needs at least read and execute by the owner, and in that case only the owner can read and execute it.

If you are worried about others reading your files you probably want to use '500' that would be read and execute for just you.

For more information and what these numbers mean (octal notation) you should read this page on Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Octal_notation

Cheers,
Darryl

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't, and even the interpreter won't be able to (and therefore won't run it).

However, you shouldn't be worried about people seeing your code; if there are eg. security flaws, you should fix them instead.